# RPART explain the predict output for type matrix

Tags: r, tree, prediction, rpart

When I  use the predict function of R(v 3.4.0) for classification tree as below it gives me an output with 10 columns.

```
p2 <- predict(mmodel,test_data,type = "matrix")
```

Output looks something like this:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]      [,10]
1       3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
5       3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
9       3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
13      3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
17      3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
21      3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
25      3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
29      3    0    0   37    0  0.0 0.00 1.00  0.0 0.37755102
```

I want to know the descriptions of these columns (on what each column represent). I have 4 classes in the data set.

I'm not sure I understand what's given on RPART documentation on this.

> If `type = "matrix"`:
>
> a matrix of the full responses (frame$yval2 if this exists, otherwise
>   frame$yval). For regression trees, this is the mean response, for
>   Poisson trees it is the response rate and the number of events at that
>   node in the fitted tree, and for classification trees  it is the
>   concatenation of at least the predicted class, the class counts at
>   that node in the fitted tree, and the class probabilities (some
>   versions of rpart may contain further columns).

Answer (score 1):

Col 1    : Level number

Cols 2-5 : 4 class frequencies

Cols 6-9 : 4 class probabilities

Col 10   : cases in that level over total number of cases (the quotient of 37 to 98 perhaps)